# Different possible arrangements in alphabetic order

Tags: combinatorics

> Q. We are given 9 letters - (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i). How many 5 letter words can be formed such that all the letters are in alphabetic order?
>
> > Case 1: Repetition is allowed (For e.g. aadff)
> >     Case 2: Repetition isn't allowed (For e.g. adghi).

How do we go about solving the problem?

Comment: Can you tell us what have you tried? Is repetition of letters while selecting allowed ? I meant, are all letters when picked from the given letters unique or not?

Comment: Further, are the letters in "aaaaa" in alphabetical order or not?

Comment: I think you have to say that aabbcd is a string of letters in alphabetical order.  Certainly if you were building a dictionary, you would have strings of that nature, and you would have a method to alphabetize the list.

Comment: @papabiceps I am sorry i did not indicate that in the problem. I will edit it. I am actually looking for both cases i.e. where repetition is and isn't allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we can choose duplicate letters and have a string in alphabetical order.

Place all the letters in alphabetical order

abcdefghi

Now place an apostophes to mark that you are selecting that letter for your string.  If a place a double apostrophe, I have selected that letter twice.

a'bcd'ef''gh'i = adffh

No matter how I place the apostrophes, I am selecting 5 letters in alphabetical order.  The identity of the letters becomes irrelevant.  The question is how many ways are there to arrange apostrophes.  And I can't place an apostrophe before the first letter.  That still gives me 13 objects to work with.

a'ooo'oo''oo'o

${13\choose 5}$

If you cannot choose duped letters (strict interpretation) the problem is a bit more obvious. ${9\choose 5}$

Comment: Just a clarification, in the second case where there are no duped letters, how can there be ${9\choose 5}$ possibilities? We cannot start word with f,g,h or i because then there wouldn't be 4 letters left to form 5 letter word.

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you choose first as you are going to put them in order *after* you pick them.  So you can start with $g$ then pick $a$ then $h$ then $d$ then $c$ to spell $acdgh$.

Answer (score 0):

1) is stars and bars.

2) is 9 choose 5.

---

1)  Take 5 toothpicks in your hand and write the letters ABCDEFGHI on a napkin.  For each letter in your word put a toothpick to the right of the letter.  Erase the letter A.  You have a mixture of letters and toothpicks.

Take a notepad and mark down 13 blank spaces.  Look at your napkin and read the letters and toothpicks for left to right.  Put an $X$ for each letter in order and put an $O$ for each toothpick.

So, if for example, you wanted the word "AACDD" you would

- Place toothpick to form $A||BC|D||EFGHI$
- Erase the $A$ to form $||BC|D||EFGHI$
- Write in the notepad $OOXXOXOOXXXXX$.

You can go the other way and for any strings of $8$ $X$s and $5$ $O$s, you can see what word they make.  For example the string $XOXOOXXXXOXOX$ becomes.

- $XOXOOXXXXOXOX$ to $*|*||****|*|*$
- $*|*||****|*|*$ to $B|C||DEFG|H|I$
- $B|C||DEFG|H|I$ to $AB|C||DEFG|H|I$
- $AB|C||DEFG|H|I$ to $BCCGH$.

So the question becomes how many ways to place $5$ $O$s and $8$ $X$s into $13$ spaces.

That's ${13 \choose 5} = \frac {13!}{5!8!}$.

2)  It's just a matter of choosing which $5$ out of $9$ to include.

That ${9 \choose 5} = \frac {9!}{5!4!}$.